# How to create a X509Certificate2 from crt and key files?

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate2

I am trying to create a X509Certificate2 with the private key. To get the private key I am traying this code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace whats_new
{
    public static class RSATest
    {
        public static void Run(string keyFile)
        {
            using var rsa = RSA.Create();

            byte[] keyBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(keyFile);
            rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(keyBytes, out int bytesRead);

            Console.WriteLine($"Read {bytesRead} bytes, {keyBytes.Length - bytesRead} extra byte(s) in file.");
            RSAParameters rsaParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
            Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(rsaParameters.D));
        }
    }
}
```

I get this code from Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#cryptographic-key-importexport

But I get the error "ASN1 corrupted data" in this line:

```
rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(keyBytes, out int bytesRead);
```

Really what I would like to do it is to create a X509Certificate2 certificate with the crt and key, because in my gRPC service I need that the certificate has both. It is because I have created the certificate with OpenSsl I generated one file for the certificate and another file for the key.

Thanks.

Comment: Your .key file is probably in the text (PEM) format, e.g. `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`.  If so, you need to extract the base64 data from between the header and the footer and Convert.FromBase64String.  (Additionally, alternatively, you need to call the Import method that matches the key file format)

Comment: right, the key and cert have this format.